Writing data to Elasticsearch 8 over NGINX reverse proxy fails when code running on Ubuntu
I have an Elasticsearch 8.12 cluster on an internal network. I use self certified certificates and everything is running well, I push data into it all the time using Python, no errors and no warnings.
I also have an Nginx reverse proxy with a proper SSL certificate which I use to provide access to Kibana from outside our network.
I recently needed to ingest data into Elasticsearch from outside our network, so I thought of doing it over the reverse proxy.
I added a proxy pass to my Elasticsearch in the reverse proxy configuration file:
    location /myelasticsearch {
    proxy_pass     https://10.10.10.20:9200/;
    }

I used the same Python 3.10 code I use internally but merely replaced the URL in the code from https://10.10.10.20:9200 to https://example.com/myelasticsearch.
If I run the code on Windows11 all works well, no errors and no warnings. If I run the same code on Ubunu 22.04 with Python 3.10 I get the following error:
elastic_transport.TlsError: TLS error caused by: SSLError([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)).
I have checked and checked the code, and the certificate. I tried writing to a different server in the cluster (after I change the proxy pass of course). The same results, the code runs with no errors on Windows, and gives the same error on Ubuntu.
I have tried the same code on WSL (Ubuntu 22.04) and I keep getting the same error. I did lots of searches on the Internet and tried different things, I downgraded urllib to 1.24, although Elasticsearch complained, I still got the same error.
I changed the Elasticsearch connection code from:
    elasticsearch = Elasticsearch([server_id], basic_auth=(user_name, elastic_pass), verify_certs=True, ca_certs=certificate_fullpath)

to :
    context = create_default_context(cafile=certificate_fullpath) 
    context.check_hostname = False
    context.hostname_checks_common_name = False
        
    elasticsearch = Elasticsearch([server_id], ssl_context=context, basic_auth=(user_name, elastic_pass))

Same issue, it works when the code is running on Windows and fails when the code is running on Ubuntu.
I added various thing to the Nginx configuration, but to no avail.
If I change verify_certs=True to verify_certs=False in the Elasticsearch connection, then data gets pushed into Elasticsearch when the code is running on Ubuntu but I get a warning that the connection is insecure.
Has anyone come across this and have they been able to solve it?
Thanks.

For anyone who encounters this issue, I have now identified and fixed the problem. I found that certificate authority from whom we bought our SSL certificate for the reverse proxy was not listed in the Ubuntu ca-certificates package.
Therefore, I added the CA certificate for the provider to the ca-certificates package on Ubuntu manually, by copying the CA certificate of the provider to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates then updated the ca-certificates using:sudo update-ca-certificates. After that all worked.
